# Filtering out statements containing items of specific types

Tags: sparql, rdf, semantic-web

I have a graph `G`. I'd like to create `G'`, a subset of `G`, by filtering out from `G` all items belonging to specific types, let's say {`:Foo`, `:Bar`}.

For example, if this is `G`

```
:x a :Foo
:y a :Bar

:x :predicate_a :hh
:kk :predicate_b :y
:mm :predicate_b :kk
```

`G'` should be:

```
:mm :predicate_b :kk
```

My <s>best</s> current option is using `DELETE` on `G`. I need two queries per each type:

(i) one for the subjects

```
delete where 
    {
        ?s ?p ?o .
        ?s a :Foo .
    }
```

(i) another one for the objects

```
delete where 
    {
        ?s ?p ?o .
        ?o a :Foo .
    }
```

In that way, I should get what I need. It seems to me that's not the best option, though. Are there better ways (i.e., more efficient/compact)?

Comment: I don't know why `DELETE` is your best option, especially if you want to have `G` *and* `G'` when you're done (which sounds like your wish).

I would suggest something like `INSERT { GRAPH :new { ?s ?p ?o } } WHERE { GRAPH :old { ?s ?p ?o FILTER ... } }`.

Comment: Actually `DELETE` is my current option more than the best one available : ) Using the approach you suggest, could there be a way to filter out all items for selected classes (i.e., `:Foo, `:Bar`) with one single query?

Comment: What is your framework? Do you need to only use SPARQL endpoints? `CONSTRUCT` can help you.

Comment: Hey @Gilles-AntoineNys! I'm working with a GraphDB repo.

Comment: As GraphDB allow managing multiples graphs, you may want to `CONSTRUCT` your second graph based on the first.

Comment: Once `CONSTRUCT`-ed I guess I need to use `INSERT` for saving new statements, as suggested by @TallTed

Comment: I mean: `CONSTRUCT` returns a graph but I need to `INSERT` for saving it :)

Comment: You could test something like `delete {?s ?p ?o} where {values (?class) {(:Foo) (:Bar)} ?s  (a|!a)|^(a|!a) ?o . ?o a ?class}` but I suppose GraphDB doesn't understand such property paths.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It can be done in a single query, using `UNION` and `VALUES`. This should work for both classes in one go:

```
PREFIX : <http://www.example.com/foo#>

DELETE { ?s ?p ?o }
WHERE
{
  VALUES (?toDeleteClass) {
    (:Foo)
    (:Bar)
  }

  ?toDelete a ?toDeleteClass 
  # or, if you want transitivity: ?toDelete a/rdfs:subClassOf* ?toDeleteClass

  { BIND( ?toDelete AS ?s ). ?s ?p ?o } 
  UNION { BIND( ?toDelete AS ?o ). ?s ?p ?o } 
}
```

Combining this with comments under your question, you can build a new graph G', rather than modifying the existing one (using `INSERT` and `GRAPH`), or, using `CONSTRUCT`, you can extract and download G' (but in this case you might need to do it in chunks, via `LIMIT`/`OFFSET`, since many triple stores have a limit about the result size a query can return).

An alternative to `VALUES` would be `FILTER ( ?toDeleteClass IN ( :Foo, :Bar )`. However, `VALUES` look more natural for the task you have and might be faster as well.

Beware of inference: if your triple store has some inference enabled by default, the pattern `?toDelete a ?toDeleteClass` might pick transitive instances of Foo/Bar too, i.e., those that are instances of subclasses of Foo/Bar, not just the direct ones. If you don't want this, the best is to find how you can disable inference in your triple store (you could detect indirect instances via `FILTER`, but it's more complicated and slower).

Comment: Ok, transitivity is only necessary in case of subclasses, right?

Comment: @floatingpurr, see the note I've added. Transitivity is for the case where Foo has subclasses Foo1 and Foo2 and you want to eliminate the instances of all the three. If you don't have such a case, just forget about transitivity :-)